# JavaScript apply() passes all arguments as one array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute external JS functions in my control by passing a function name and using apply().

I'm using solution found on stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

```
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
    var func = namespaces.pop();
    for (var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
        context = context[namespaces[i]];
    }
    return context[func].apply(context, args);
}
```

Function usage:

```
var functionName = 'MyFunction';
executeFunctionByName(functionName, window, [e, data]);
```

Function **MyFunction**:

```
function MyFunction(e, data){
    // e <- this is an array [e, data]
    // data <- this is undefined
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/4zc42wh1(v=vs.94).aspx) `apply()` should pass arguments as they are in function definition, not as an array.

Is there a way to make it work the way described in documentation?

Can it have something to do with the context set to `window`?

Comment: `executeFunctionByName(functionName, window, e, data);`

Comment: The documentation for `apply` in that page does say that it has to be array `apply([thisObj[,argArray]])`, but when you call the function you should pass each argument, not an array.

Comment: The root cause, I guess, is you didn't get what [**`Array.prototype.slice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) was doing.

Comment: I missed that nested array, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

try

```
console.log(args); // [[e, data]], array in array... got it?
```

So there are 2 ways:

1)

`executeFunctionByName(functionName, window, [e, data]);`

to

```
executeFunctionByName(functionName, window, e, data);
```

2)

`var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);`

to

```
var args = arguments[2]; //or name the third input parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is just fine. The problem is that you have a doubly-nested array.

When you call `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);`, that itself returns an array, containing *another* array.

You're passing `[[e, data]]` to apply, not `[e, data]`.

There are two solutions, depending on how you want to fix the problem:

1. If you want to keep invoking your method this way:

   ```
   executeFunctionByName(functionName, window, [e, data]);
   ```

   Then you have absolutely no need for `Array.prototype.slice` on `arguments`. You have a predictable number of arguments, it's *always 3*. Just write your function this way:

   ```
   function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context, args) {
     var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
     // ....
     return context[func].apply(context, args);
   }
   ```
2. If you want to keep using `Array.prototype.slice` in your function, you need to change how you invoke the function.  Your arguments should not be wrapped in an array:

   ```
   executeFunctionByName(functionName, window, e, data);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should be able to call it with either the e or the data, but not both.

I would do it something like this:

```
function MyFunction(data){
   //Some action with your data
}
```

and call it with:

```
executeFunctionByName(functionName, window, [data]);
```

Where data is some array of data. I think the documentation on Mozilla's page explains it more clearly, it can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply